# byte array to string and back. Confused

Tags: c#

What is wrong with this code?  Why the differences?

```
byte [] data = new byte [] {0x21, 0x4B, 0x9B, 0xE1, 0x2D, 0xA7, 0x4B, 0x93, 0x1E, 0x3F, 0xDA, 0x4F, 0xB1};
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(data));

string dataStr = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data);       
byte[] ca = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataStr);
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(ca));
```

**Output:**

> 21-4B-9B-E1-2D-A7-4B-93-1E-3F-DA-4F-B1
>
> 21-4B-3F-3F-2D-3F-4B-3F-1E-3F-3F-4F-3F

Comment: Thanks to commenter for finding the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII doesn't define character codes above `7F`, and it seems that `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString()` chooses to replace invalid bytes with `3F`, which represents the character `?`.

You might want to read [Joel Spolsky's excellent article on encoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).